# Some sites and apps won't work on network

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dns, android

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04  on Lenovo ThinkPad laptop and I have internet T-mobile provider (Austria). When I connect directly to WiFi of their router some websites are not working - simply like they don't exist at all. Also some apps like Skype and Slack are not working.

However, same sites are opening from my android phone, connected to the same home WiFi. More ever, if I open hotspot on my phone, which is still connected to my home WiFi all sites and apps are working on my laptop?!?

I also tried setting Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.) to on my laptop for router WiFi connection and I think that helped me only once, shortly (I was able to open the site that won't work) but immediately it sopped working.

I have "tailscale" installed, but I run it  only when needed, so most of the time (also when I was testing) it's not running.

Any idea what could be wrong there? How android phone manages to "fix" this issue?